# Taxonomy checkboxes not showing current status on edit page

Tags: posts, taxonomy, post-editor

Super strange thing happening on post pages, the Categories dropdown and checkboxes when clicked show no change, however after clicking save, or waiting for autosave the checkbox changes it's appearance to reflect.

Wnaything I've done here to make this happen or maybe a bug?

wordpress v5.2 – I renamed the post pages to News in functions.php as follows:

```
function change_post_menu_label() {
    global $menu;
    global $submenu;
    $menu[5][0] = 'News';
    $submenu['edit.php'][5][0] = 'News Items';
    $submenu['edit.php'][10][0] = 'Add News Item';
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'change_post_menu_label' );
```

Comment: That function won't do anything on its own. It would need to be hooked. Have you done that? What hook are you using?

Comment: Yep there is the hook there too. pretty sure this isn't the issue, but thought I'd put it up just in case